# KendoUI scheduler getting data from database based on dates

Tags: kendo-ui, scheduler

I am trying to get the KendoUI scheduler to retrieve only the data for the selected view (day, week, month) from the database.
Has anyone been able to do this ? Or can anyone point me in the right direction ?
Have been running in circles for a day....

Answer (score 0):

There is code library project which does that (uses ASP.NET MVC as a backend): http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/mvc/scheduler/server-filtering.aspx